# How would I remove nth-of-type styles using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

While attempting to remove the display style from some classes using javascript, I keep get the following error:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined".
```

My wish is to hide all posts after the 6th one and then eventually use a button with the `onclick` function to display 6 more at a time. Any help is appreciated.

JavaScript

```
 onclick="myFunction()"
 function myFunction(){
var post = document.getElementsByClassName('justify.-column:nth-of-type');
post[10].style.display = 'block'
}
```

CSS

```
.author-posts-list{
 .justify.-column:nth-of-type(1n + 7){
     display: none;
   } 
 }
```

Comment: (1) it's not a class name (2) compare the selector in the JS and the one in the CSS

Comment: The `.getElementsByClassName()` function expects a list of class names separated by a space; you may be looking for `.querySelectorAll()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To query by available CSS selectors and return all in a node list use `querySelectorAll`. You can choose to use the pseudo selector in full in your query or exclude it and select by index.

```
var post = document.querySelectorAll('justify.-column');
```

or

```
var post = document.querySelectorAll('justify.-column:nth-of-type(1n + 7)');
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you! I completely forgot about querySelector

Comment: @MarselGray Feel free to mark as correct to help others. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers